# In networkx, is hovering and double click on a node possible like html?

Tags: python, networkx, dhtml

I am looking for a solution I can make nodes in python clickable. And when clicked, it should call another page/function.

Comment: networkx uses matplotlib to plot the graphs, in that this functionality is not available but you can use other modules such as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456723/networkx-add-hyperlink-to-each-node