# How to hyperlink nodes in d3js NetworkX diGraph

Tags: python, d3.js, networkx

I would like to create a NetworkX graph and visualize it using d3js similarly to
the javascript [example](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/external/javascript_force.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-external-javascript-force-py) in the NetworkX docs. This graph is very similar to the interactive graph on the NetworkX homepage [page](https://networkx.org/).

The example works for me, but I would like to add hyperlinks to the nodes. I think I have node attributes called "xlink:href", but I have not figured out how.

This question was ansered for NewtworkX and visualization with bokeh [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456723/networkx-add-hyperlink-to-each-node). I have not tested this example, since I want to use d3js. The code below is available [here](https://gist.github.com/BjornFJohansson/a60d754bf6330852c5b683e1dafbf2d4).

So far:

```
import json
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('Node1')
G.add_node('Node2')
G.add_edge('Node1', 'Node2')

for n in G:
    G.nodes[n]["name"] = "My" + str(n) 
    G.nodes[n]["xlink:href"] = "http://google.com"  # <==<< link Not working

d = nx.json_graph.node_link_data(G)

json.dump(d, open("force/force.json", "w"))
print("Wrote node-link JSON data to force/force.json")
```

The above produces:

```
{'directed': False,
 'multigraph': False,
 'graph': {},
 'nodes': [{'name': 'MyNode1',
   'xlink:href': 'http://google.com',
   'id': 'Node1'},
  {'name': 'MyNode2', 'xlink:href': 'http://google.com', 'id': 'Node2'}],
 'links': [{'source': 'Node1', 'target': 'Node2'}]}
```

Which can be visualized like this:

```
# Serve the file over http to allow for cross origin requests
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__, static_folder="force")

@app.route("/")
def static_proxy():
    return app.send_static_file("force.html")
app.run(port=8001)
```

[image]

Interestingly, the tooltip on the graph displays "Node2" and not "MyNode2".

Links collected while trying to solve this:

- https://github.com/simonlindgren/nXd3
- http://www.d3noob.org/2014/05/including-html-link-in-d3js-tool-tip.html
- https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/json_graph.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [gravis](https://robert-haas.github.io/gravis-docs/), which accepts graph objects from NetworkX, iGraph, graph-tool and some other Python libraries and can visualize them with either d3.js, vis.js or three.js with a single function call.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of gravis. Your use case appears to be 1) creating an interactive graph visualization with d3 and 2) serve it via a web server such as Flask. Since this was part of the motivation to build gravis, I think it might fit well here.

```
import gravis as gv
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_node('Node1')
g.add_node('Node2')
g.add_edge('Node1', 'Node2')

for n in g:
    g.nodes[n]["name"] = f"My {n}" 
    g.nodes[n]["hover"] = '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>'

fig = gv.d3(g, node_label_data_source='name')
fig.display()
```

The last line opens a browser window and shows the visualization. Alternatively you can also use `fig.to_html()` to get a standalone HTML text that you can serve via a web server like Flask. The hyperlink is shown when hovering over a node and can easily be clicked since the pop up disappears with a time delay.

Yet another use case that can easily be serve is creating embedded graph visualizations in a Jupyter notebook, which may help in prototyping your app:
[image]

(The mouse cursor was hidden from the screenshot. It's hovering over node 1, hence the pop up with the hyperlink is visible.)

Answer (score 1):

I never used *JavaScript* but seems like you just need to update [line 36](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/62288244a7356db0d7def7bd532d05457f567301/examples/external/force/force.js#L36) of `force.js` :

```
    node.append("title")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.name; // << instead of d.id
        });
```

Preview (*at http://127.0.0.1:8001/*) :

[image]

Comment: I see. I didnt even think about that all. Probably I would have to modify force.js to anable links as well.

Answer (score 0):

I made this from @Robert Haas answer. This code saves a standalone html file
with all the needed javascript and the links to local files (snippet1.md and snippet2.md) from the nodes by hovering.

```
import gravis as gv
import networkx as nx
from pathlib import Path

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_node('Node1')
g.add_node('Node2')
g.add_edge('Node1', 'Node2')

g.nodes['Node1']["name"] = f"MyNode1"
g.nodes['Node1']["hover"] = '<a href="snippet1.md">snippet1</a>'

g.nodes['Node2']["name"] = f"MyNode2"
g.nodes['Node2']["hover"] = '<a href="snippet2.md">snippet2</a>'

fig = gv.d3(g, node_label_data_source='name')

page = fig.to_html_standalone()

Path("gravis.html").write_text(page)
```